# Train Dispatcher in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am developing a simplified train dispatch system as a final assessment for my CS major, first semester. I have a user interface class, with the TrainDispatch instance as a UI class variable.

Furthermore, I have one UserInputHandler class and a InputValidator class. I need some methods from the TrainDispatch system in the InputValidator class. So, my question is:

Should I use the TrainDispatch instance in the UI class as a parameter in the UI methods that call methods in the UserInputHandler, where these methods again call some methods in the InputValidator class, or should I create a new TrainDispatch instance directly in the InputValidator class?

A method in UI:

```
private int validateAndGetTrainNumberToFindDeparture() {
  return userInputHandler.validateTrainNumberToFindDeparture(trainDispatch);
```

}

The corresponding method in UserInputValidator:

```
public int validateTrainNumberToFindDeparture(TrainDispatch trainDispatch) {
  System.out.print("\nTrain number, max 4 digits. Press 0 to exit: ");
  // asks for right format until user input is valid
  while (true) {
    String trainNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
      // Check if the user wants to exit
      if (trainNumber.equals("0")) {
        return 0;
      }
      // if input is valid (validation method does not throw exception), return new time
      return inputValidator.validateTrainNumberToFind(trainNumber, trainDispatch);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.print(WRONG_FORMAT);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      System.out.print(e.getMessage() + PLEASE_TRY_AGAIN + " (0 to exit): ");
    }
  }
}
```

And again, the corresponding method in InputValidator:

```
public int validateTrainNumberToFind(String trainNumber, TrainDispatch trainDispatch) {
  if (trainNumber.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(INPUT_CANNOT_BE_EMPTY);
  }
  int trainNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(trainNumber);
  if (trainNumberInt <= 0 || trainNumberInt > 9999) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Train number has to be positive and max 4 digits. ");
  }
  if (!trainDispatch.findDuplicateTrainNumber(trainNumberInt)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Train number does not exist. ");
  }
  return trainNumberInt;
}
```

Is this better than creating a new TrainDispatch instance in the InputValidators, for example in terms of low coupling?

The system works fine, I just wonder what the better approach is.